# Quotient group (matrices)

Tags: matrices, group-theory, quotient-group

What group do we obtain when we quotient $\mathrm{GL}_2 (\mathbb Z )$ by $\mathrm{  SL}_2 (\mathbb Z) $ ?

Comment: Well a matrix is invertible over $\Bbb Z$ means it's determinant is $\pm1$.  $SL_2(\Bbb Z)$ is the subset of determiant one.  So I'm guessing it's $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: What have you tried in this respect?  What is a quotient group?  Do you know each of the groups you name in your question?  That's a good place to start for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah map $GL_2(\Bbb Z)$ to $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ by $M\mapsto\det(M)$.  The kernel is $SL_2(\Bbb Z)$.  So the quotient is $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Define $\phi: \mathbb{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \to \{1,-1\}$ by sending $A \to \det(A)$. Look at the Kernel of this map and use Fundamental Homomorphism Theorem.